# MYSQL stored procedure with nullable parameter which is then set if is null

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to have a 'optional' parameter in the sproc, I understand that's not allowed in MYSQL but I plan to pass it null then check and set it if it is null. However I think my syntax is out, I suspect something with my delimiters but I can't see why it is wrong.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `addSensorReading`(
      _temp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _mois DECIMAL(5,2), 
      sourceName varchar(15), 
      _ambTemp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _ambMois DECIMAL(5,2)
      )

IF (_ambTemp IS NULL) THEN
    SET _ambTemp := (   SELECT      r.ambTempValue
                        FROM        Readings r
                        WHERE       r.ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
                        ORDER BY    r.creation_time DESC
                        LIMIT       1);
END IF;

IF (_ambMois IS NULL) THEN
    SET _ambMois := (   SELECT      r.ambMoisValue
                        FROM        Readings r
                        WHERE       r.ambMoisValue IS NOT NULL
                        ORDER BY    r.creation_time DESC
                        LIMIT       1);
END IF;


INSERT INTO reading (moisValue, tempValue, sourceName, ambTempValue, ambMoisValue)
    VALUES (_mois, _temp, sourceName, _ambTemp, _ambMois);;


DELIMITER ;
```

Barmar gave the answer:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `addSensorReading`(
      _temp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _mois DECIMAL(5,2), 
      sourceName varchar(15), 
      _ambTemp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _ambMois DECIMAL(5,2)
      )
BEGIN
/*we only get ambient readings from the api every 2 hours (that's how often it updates), so for ease of UI and readability we assume it has not changed as there is no more recent reading. So we get the latest reading with an ambient value if we don't have one provided. */
INSERT INTO Reading (moisValue, tempValue, sourceName, ambTempValue, ambMoisValue)
SELECT _mois, _temp, sourceName, IFNULL(_ambTemp, r1.ambTempValue), IFNULL(_ambMois, r2.ambMoisValue)
FROM (SELECT ambTempValue
        FROM Reading
        WHERE ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY creation_time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS r1
CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ambMoisValue
        FROM Reading
        WHERE ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY creation_time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS r2

END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Which results in the error: 'Query was empty'

Apologies in advance I'm much more familiar with SQL server, which seems much more adept at local variables and spocs in general.
Thanks

Comment: Always post the FULL error message reported when asking questions like this, please.

Comment: when I run this I get the error: "Query was empty "

However both the sub selects return a value?

Comment: What are you using to define the procedure? MySQL Workbench, PhpMyAdmin, the `mysql` CLI? The error message you're getting indicates that you're sending an empty query to MySQL when you're trying to create the procedure.

Comment: I'm using SQL Pro on a mac, this is the only code in the query that I'm running

Comment: I've tried running it against php myadmin and this is the error I'm getting: 
https://imgur.com/aZNm5f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGIN` and `END` are optional in Transact-SQL, not in other versions of SQL.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `addSensorReading`(
      _temp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _mois DECIMAL(5,2), 
      sourceName varchar(15), 
      _ambTemp DECIMAL(5,2), 
      _ambMois DECIMAL(5,2)
      )
BEGIN    
IF (_ambTemp IS NULL) THEN
    SET _ambTemp := (   SELECT      r.ambTempValue
                        FROM        Readings r
                        WHERE       r.ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
                        ORDER BY    r.creation_time DESC
                        LIMIT       1);
END IF;

IF (_ambMois IS NULL) THEN
    SET _ambMois := (   SELECT      r.ambMoisValue
                        FROM        Readings r
                        WHERE       r.ambMoisValue IS NOT NULL
                        ORDER BY    r.creation_time DESC
                        LIMIT       1);
END IF;


INSERT INTO reading (moisValue, tempValue, sourceName, ambTempValue, ambMoisValue)
    VALUES (_mois, _temp, sourceName, _ambTemp, _ambMois);
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: okay thanks that makes sense, in TSQL I would just use GO as a batch separator, does that work the same here?

Comment: when I run this I get the error: Query was empty

However both the sub selects return a value?

Answer (score 0):

Try combining everything into a single INSERT query.

```
INSERT INTO reading (moisValue, tempValue, sourceName, ambTempValue, ambMoisValue)
SELECT _mois, _temp, sourceName, IFNULL(_ambTemp, r1.ambTempValue), IFNULL(_ambMois, r2.ambMoisValue)
FROM (SELECT ambTempValue
        FROM Reading
        WHERE ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY creation_time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS r1
CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ambMoisValue
        FROM Reading
        WHERE ambTempValue IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY creation_time DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS r2
```

Comment: I still get the error "Query was empty"
The sub selects should be from Reading not Readings, but that's still giving the error.
Both the sub selects return a value

Comment: Maybe the error is coming from how you call the procedure, not from the queries inside the procecdure.

Comment: When I search for that error message, all the examples come from calling `mysql_query()` incorrectly, not from a problem in the SQL itself.

Comment: The error is when I try to define the procedure, haven't got to calling it yet

Comment: I've updated the main question with the updated code, the Reading table does have values and the subselects both complete, I still can't define the stored procedure

Comment: If you can't define the procedure, it doesn't matter what happens in the subselects.